# Error while finding topics quantity on Latent Dirichlet Allocation model using ldatuning library

Tags: text-mining, lda, text2vec

This is the outcome error and I can tell this is because there is at least one document without some term, but I don't get why and how I can solve it.

```
prep_fun = function(x) {
  x %>% 
    str_to_lower                         %>%   #make text lower case
    str_replace_all("[^[:alpha:]]", " ") %>%   #remove non-alpha symbols - chao punctuation y #
    str_replace_all("\\s+", " ")         %>%   #collapse multiple spaces 
    str_replace_all("\\W*\\b\\w\\b\\W*", " ")  #Remuevo letras individuales
}
tok_fun <- function(x) {
  tokens <- word_tokenizer(x)
  textstem::lemmatize_words(tokens)
}
it_patentes <- itoken(data$Abstract, 
                      preprocessor = prep_fun, 
                      tokenizer = tok_fun, 
                      ids = data$id,
                      progressbar = F)
vocab <- create_vocabulary(it_patentes, ngram = c(ngram_min = 1L, ngram_max = 3L), 
                           stopwords = tm::stopwords("english"))
pruned_vocab <- prune_vocabulary(vocab, term_count_min =  max(vocab$term_count)*.01, 
                                 doc_proportion_min = 0.001)   
vectorizer <- vocab_vectorizer(pruned_vocab) 
dtm <- create_dtm(it_patentes, vectorizer,type = "dgTMatrix", progressbar = FALSE)   

> #Plot the metrics to get number of topics 
> t1 <- Sys.time()
> tunes <- FindTopicsNumber(
+   dtm = dtm,
+   topics = c(2:25),
+   metrics = c("Griffiths2004", "CaoJuan2009", "Arun2010"),
+   method = "Gibbs",
+   control = list(seed = 17),
+   mc.cores = 4L,
+   verbose = TRUE
+ )
fit models...Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  4 nodes produced errors; first error: Each row of the input matrix needs to contain at least one non-zero entry
> print(difftime(Sys.time(), t1, units = 'sec'))
Time difference of 9.155343 secs
> FindTopicsNumber_plot(tunes)
Error in base::subset(values, select = 2:ncol(values)) : 
  object 'tunes' not found
```

Even though I know ldatuning is made for topicmodels, I don't think there might be a huge difference to get a number to start testing, is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ldatuning` expects input `dtm` matrix in a different format (format from `topicmodels` package). You need to convert `dtm` (sparse matrix from Matrix package) to a format which `ldatuning` can understand

Comment: Thanks, all I did was removing those documents which had 0 entries and it gives out an outcome because they were only 400, is it ok to follow that outcome or is ther any other way that I can calculate group number indicators for text2vec automatically?